# ptrace watchpoint on register

Tags: c, ptrace

I am writing a C-Program with some debugging functionality.
I need to set a breakpoint on register access of the ptraced process.
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Any register in particular?  A CPU does "register access" every cycle.

Comment: Yes, I want to stop the traced process if for example the rax register is read or written.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
watch $rax
```

in gdb console. Hope it helps.